# Visual disable xamarin references

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have little problem with Xamarin and my project. Whole project just lost references and with that what visual say in use are all "using" libraries what i'm sure is false [image: pic1]. Problem exist only in this project [image: pic2]

**resharper not installed**

**Don't work:**

- clean Solution/project
- restart Visual Stutio 2015

Comment: There is no way to know what you did with the project for it to "just lost references". I'd recommend comparing to previous version if you use source control (if you don't - good time to start, I'd recommend Git... I.e. https://github.com/ or company I work for provides Git repositories - https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/git/)... If you don't use source control creating clean project and copying code from old one probably the fastest way to recover.

Comment: For luck i'm using git :) but it really hapend

Comment: Please post a  [diagnostic build output](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/#Diagnostic_MSBuild_Output), that would be really appreciated!